# Find out Total Number of Rows affected by SQL Command Variable in Data Flow Task

Tags: csv, ssis, ssis-2012

I have  **SQL Command From Variable (In General it is  a Select Statement)** as a Source  in DataFlow Task.
Destination is **.csv File**.

Problem: Even though no rows is affected by SQL command Variable .csv file is generating without records. I don't want to generate the file if the select statement (from SQL command variable) populate no records.

Please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

Simple procedure:
you could count the rows with a query before export, using Execute SQL Task, if the number of rows is greater than 0 then proceed with the export;
The following is a possible solution:

- use a query like SELEC COUNT(*) AS MYCOUNT FROM...
- use a package variable (myVariable to associate with MYCOUNT), to contain the number of rows
- set Result Set = Single Row in SQL Task Editor
- map the variable in tab Result Set in SQL Task Editor (MYCOUNT - myVariable)
- use two arrows from Execute SQL Task in each arrow choose Evaluation operation: Expression, Expression: myVariable > 0 (first arrow) and myVariable == 0 (second arrow), choose Logical OR, in this way you have a bifurcation!
- connect the export to the arrow with myVariable > 0
- connect the other arrow to another possible task, for example it can warn you that there are no rows via email

For counting rows can also use the task: **Row Count** (present in the latest SSIS versions); the Row Count transformation counts rows as they pass through a data flow and stores the final count in a variable.

I hope it help

Comment: Thank you Alex.
But I have a diff. Scenario. There is a foreach loop container  with Foreach From Variable Enumerator. Based on that Variable script task creates sqlCommand query which is passed into Data Flow task source as SQLcommad from Variable. YES I have used row count function but eventually it goes to Data flow task destination and creates a .csv File.

Comment: Thank you too, 
Why not also dynamically create the query counting rows (within a Variable) and then 
place the verification of the number of rows (Execute SQL Task with query from Variable) before the Data Flow Task ? 
In this way you're still inside the loop..

Comment: Yes Alex this is one Solution.  Is there other approach so that we know there is no records affected by Dataflow task source (SQLCommand from Variables) and divert not to generate the output file.